# action client stuck waiting on server

Tags: ros, action, ros-kinetic, server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been trying to write an action file (cpp) using the Fibonacci example as a guide but so far it's just getting stuck on starting the server and i can't quite see why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>

#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <actionlib/server/simple_action_server.h>
#include <actionlib/client/simple_action_client.h>

#include <mavros_msgs/SetMode.h>
#include <mavros_msgs/CommandBool.h>

#include <rovexp/ModeAction.h>

typedef actionlib::SimpleActionServer<rovexp::ModeAction> Server;
class ModeActionServer {
protected:
    ros::NodeHandle nh_;
    
    ros::ServiceClient arming_client_;
    ros::ServiceClient set_mode_client_;
    
    Server mode_server_;
    
    rovexp::ModeFeedback feedback_;
    rovexp::ModeResult result_;
    std::string action_name_;
public:
    ModeActionServer(std::string name) :
        mode_server_(nh_, name, boost::bind(&ModeActionServer::executeCB, this, _1), false),
        action_name_(name)
    {
        mode_server_.start();
        ROS_INFO("Mode action server started...");
    }
    ~ModeActionServer(void) { }
    
    void executeCB(const rovexp::ModeGoalConstPtr &goal)
    {
        ROS_INFO_STREAM("mode experiment started...");
        
        /*
        set_mode_client_ = nh_.serviceClient<mavros_msgs::SetMode>("mavros/set_mode");
        mavros_msgs::SetMode offb_set_mode;
        offb_set_mode.request.custom_mode = goal->mode_num;
        
        set_mode_client_.call(offb_set_mode);
        */
        
        arming_client_ = nh_.serviceClient<mavros_msgs::CommandBool>("mavros/cmd/arming");
        ros::Rate rate(20.0);
        mavros_msgs::CommandBool arm_cmd;
        arm_cmd.request.value = true;
        arming_client_.call(arm_cmd);
    }
};

typedef actionlib::SimpleActionClient<rovexp::ModeAction> Client;
void modeActionClient(uint8_t mode_num)
{
    Client client("mode_client", true);
    
    ROS_INFO("Waiting for action server to start");
    client.waitForServer();
    
    rovexp::ModeGoal goal;
    goal.mode_num = mode_num;
    printf("%d\t4\n",goal.mode_num);
    client.sendGoal(goal);
    
    client.waitForResult();
}

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    if(std::string(argv[1])=="-server")
    {
      ros::init(argc, argv, "mode_server");
      ModeActionServer server("mode_server");
      //server.start();
      ros::spin();

    }
    else if(std::string(argv[1])=="-client")
    {
        if ( std::string(argv[2])=="-h" ) {
            printf("Use: rosrun rovexp mode -client @mode\n"); 
            exit(-1);
        }
        ros::init(argc, argv, "mode_action_client");
        uint8_t mode_num = atoi(argv[2]);
        modeActionClient(mode_num);
    }
    printf("done\n");   
    return 0;
}
```

This is the action cpp file. After running the server and the client I get both "Mode action server started..." and "Waiting for action server to start" so I figure that means the client is getting caught up on `ROS_INFO_STREAM("mode experiment started...");`. I'm not quite sure why the server is taking so long to start up. I've also attempted the Fibonacci example in [link](https://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials/RunningServerAndClient) and that works fine.

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and ROS Kinetic.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/325236/action-client-stuck-waiting-on-server/) by [morten_nissov](https://answers.ros.org/users/42355/morten_nissov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2019-06-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> ModeActionServer server("mode_server");
> ```

and

> ```
> Client client("mode_client", true);
> ```

If I'm not mistaken, the first argument to the ctor would be the namespace the client uses to communicate with the server ([docs](https://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/actionlib/html/classactionlib_1_1SimpleActionClient.html#a416667d5c870abc27227e45a492c1e3f)).

You set that to `mode_server` for the server, but to `mode_client` for the client.

That would make them unable to find each other, causing the client to wait for the server to come up.

The example server and client you mention use `fibonacci` for both the server and the client. That's probably why that version of the code does "work".

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [morten_nissov](https://answers.ros.org/users/42355/morten_nissov/) on 2019-06-11**:
I didn't notice that at all but yeah after doing that it works when run off a roscore on my computer.

I'm currently using ROS within the frame of an underwater ROV. When I connect to the robot and use the robot's address as the master_uri instead the same problem occurs.

Am I missing some mavros library or something?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-11**:\

> I didn't notice that at all but yeah after doing that it works when run off a roscore on my computer.

Good. So your question has been answered.

> I'm currently using ROS within the frame of an underwater ROV. When I connect to the robot and use the robot's address as the master_uri instead the same problem occurs.

that would be a different question, and it's bad form to post follow-up questions in comments.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-11**:
I would suggest to lookup older Q&As about multi-host network setups and ROS, as it's most likely a problem with you using *hostnames* and not having a working DNS that is able to resolve all names into IPs. To check whether that is the case, set `ROS_IP` on all involved hosts and try again.

**Comment by [morten_nissov](https://answers.ros.org/users/42355/morten_nissov/) on 2019-06-16**:
Thanks for the advice. And sorry I had totally forgotten to do that.